# How to fix a solution similar to Counting Sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I wanted to check if frequency of minimum element is odd: I would print lucky, otherwise print "Unlucky".
I used a technique related to counting sort arr[arr1[i]]++ counting duplicated as value and reference to the actual value to it's INDEX. I tried with this but it didn't bring the correct answer [appreciate if you correct my code rather than a new different solution]

input: 6 6 6 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 7 7

output: Unlucky

since the minimum frequency is 7, 7%2!=0 so Unlucky

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=in.nextInt();
    while(t-->0) {      //Test cases
    int n=in.nextInt();//array's length

    int arr[]=new int[n];// array
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        arr[i]=in.nextInt();
    }
    int counter[]=new int[256];//counting duplicates
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        counter[arr[i]]++;
    }
    int min=1;
    int pos=0;
    for(int i=0;i<counter.length;i++) {
        if(counter[i]<min && counter[i]!=0) { //search for minimal frequency (counter[i]!=0 since our counter array could easily have lot zeroes
            min=counter[i];
            pos=i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println((pos%2==0)?"Unlucky":"Lucky");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect time for you to learn how to *debug* your code, and how to use a *debugger* to step through it statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: If you want more help then please [edit] your question to include a full copy-paste (as text) of your assignment, including all requirements and limitations (which hopefully includes where the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) `256` comes from). Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to the while loop and other loop for `counter`, you assign the array using `n` variable, 
then you enter values to the `arr` and check frequency in the same loop.
And select the min frequency to check if it's `lucky` or `not`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();// array's length

        int arr[] = new int[n];// array
        int counter[] = new int[n];
        int min = 1;
        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
            counter[arr[i]]++;
            if (counter[i] < min && counter[i] != 0) {
                min = counter[i];
                pos = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println((pos % 2 == 0) ? "Unlucky" : "Lucky");
        in.close();
    }
```

, input

```
12 6 6 6 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 7 7
```

, output

```
Unlucky
```

Comment: Please take some time to read (or refresh) [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers without any kind of explanation or description of the changes made are really not very helpful. And if the change is small, then describe and show only that, instead of the full program.

Comment: Thank i'm new <3 i will try to explain more and lesser code

Comment: The message was not referred to you @Fares_Essayeh but to the user who replied to you.

Comment: @Fares_Essayeh could you approve the answer. So the others can use it confidently.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following points:

1. Your program is less useful/efficient for three reasons: **(A)** It will work for integers from 0 to 255 only **(B)** You are using a fixed size array of size 256 which means that even if the user enters just a few numbers, it will consume space for 256 integers **(C)** You are iterating the loop 256 times to calculate the frequency even if the user enters just a few numbers.
2. There are so many ways to count the frequency of numbers. Commonly people use a `Map` to do so. I've used the same thing in the function, `minFrequencyNumber` shown below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the size of array: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        System.out.print("Enter " + n + " integers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("The number with minimum frequency is: " + minFrequencyNumber(arr));
        System.out.println((minFrequencyNumber(arr) % 2 == 0) ? "Unlucky" : "Lucky");
    }

    public static int minFrequencyNumber(int[] arr) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
        // Iterate the array
        for (int i : arr) {
            // If the number does not exist in the Map, put the number as the key and 1 as
            // the value (frequency); otherwise, put the number as the key in the map by
            // increasing its value (frequency) by 1
            m.put(i, m.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);
        }
        int num = 0, minFrequency = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        // Iterate the map
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> e : m.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getValue() < minFrequency) {
                minFrequency = e.getValue();
                // Store the key (the number) whose frequency is minimum
                num = e.getKey();
            }
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the size of array: 12
Enter 12 integers: 6 6 6 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 7 7
The number with minimum frequency is: 7
Lucky
```

Comment: your answer is great i'm' not familliar with hashing but it's seems your solution is way optimised and i did not dislike your post i will take it as example as long i understand the fundemntals of Hashing, maping ,etc

Comment: Thanks, @Fares_Essayeh for the feedback.